# Retrieve data from mysql on date selection

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

```
$query  = "select * from researchsub_form where  flag='1' and date between '$date' and '$date1' ";
```

I have two input, date and date1, I have to show the data from database between the date 'date' and 'date1' of flag='1', for this I use a SQL query, but I want to show the data when I enter only one date input which is either 'date' or 'date1'

Comment: Then it is pointless to use `between` and `and` ..directly give `where date=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from researchsub_form where flag='1' and (date between '$date' and '$date1' or date='$date' or date='$date1')

Comment: when i input the date in date1 then it will shows all entry upto date1from the database having flag=1

Answer (score 0):

You can create your condition where in dynamic.

```
$query = "select * from researchsub_form where flag='1'";

if(isset($date) && isset($date1)) 
    $condition += " and date between '$date' and '$date1'";
else if(isset($date)) 
    $condition += " and date > '$date'";
else if(isset($date1)) 
    $condition += " and date < '$date1'";

$query += $condition;
```

Or you can assign to date the smalles date (1753), to date1 the biggest (9999) when one of them is empty, but its not good.